# Calculus Number question

Tags: calculus

[image]

I got this question from a friend who was trying to solve this, and I am currently having trouble with the proof. I know that $t_n$ is the fractional part of the sum of the sequence and the sequence diverges. Now, I'm trying to find a proof that there are infinitely many sums $t_i$ which when $l$ subtracted from $t_i$ gives $\pm\epsilon$. So how can I proceed in this proof?

Comment: You don't know that the sequence is of the form $\frac 1{x^n}$.  It could have many other forms as long as it does not go to $0$ fast enough for the sum to converge.

Comment: yes, but then it must converge to 0 eventually(so the value is fractional, with x as denominator), and then if n is larger than 1, the series converges?

Comment: Yes, it must converge to $0$, but there doesn't have to be a neat pattern like $\frac 1{x^n}$ at all (and it should be $\frac 1{n^x}$ as the terms are numbered by $n$).  It could be a bunch of numbers that bounce around but get smaller and smaller overall, like a uniform random between $0$ and $1$ divided by $n$.  The division by $n$ gives convergence to $0$, but often the value will increase instead of decreasing.  Noting this should eliminate some extraneous things from your thinking.

Comment: ah, i understand that now. So the sequence eventually reaches 0 and diverges, can be anything as long as it converges. But then, the sums of the terms in the sequence t_i take an accumulation point, then there will be infinite possible accumulation points eventually.

Comment: The fact that $a_n \to 0$ says that there is some $N$ such that for all $n \gt N, a_n \lt \frac 1{1000}$, for example.  Let us ignore all earlier $n$.  What does the fact that $s_n$ diverges tell you about the behavior of $t_n$ in this range?

Comment: ah. therefore tn in this range diverges. So do you mean that generally, for every section of the series by cutting off the left, the right side always diverges.

Comment: Yes, convergence or divergence is determined by what happens late in the series.  You can change the early terms any way you like without changing it.  In this case early means any finite number of terms as long as the changes eventually stop.  $t_n$ is always between $0$ and $1$, so it doesn't go off to infinity as $s_n$ does.

Comment: now if we get to the accumulation point, since the series converges to 0 and diverges, then there is a certain range of values round l which works. but how can that possibly be infinite?

Comment: I don't understand the last comment.  The series is the $a_n$, which converge to $0$.  What diverges is the $s_n$.  What do you mean there is a range of values around $1$ that works?  Values of what?  that works how?  what is supposed to be infinite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116743/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-citruscornflakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the points between 0 and 1 will be accumulation points. Instead of writing out a formal proof I'll just note that because the series diverges one keeps "re-starting" in the modulo 1 arithmetic, and because the terms converge to 0 one moves up in smaller and smaller steps so that all points between 0 and 1 will be revisited arbitrarily closely arbitrarily many times.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand now!